# Take file as input to function - Posix shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, posix

I am writing a function in a Posix shell script that compresses files if an env variable is set to true, then that file is pushed to a remote location. Instead of just compressing one global file, how would I pass any number of files to be compressed as parameters to the function? Below is my code:

`CODE:`

```
#!/bin/sh

COMPRESSION=true

FILE="test.json"
LOG_FILE="test.log"

compress_file() {
    gzip $FILE
    stat $FILE.gz
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
        FILE=$FILE.gz 
    else 
        FILE=$FILE
    fi
}

push_file() {
    FILE=$1
    cmd() {
        STORAGE_URL="https://somepath"
        TIMESTAMP=$(date -u '+%a, %d %b %Y %T GMT')
        
        if [ "$COMPRESSION" = true ]; then
            compress_file
            CONTENT_TYPE="'content-type: application/gzip'"
        else
            CONTENT_TYPE="'content-type: application/json'"
        fi
        
        curl --fail --silent --show-error -X PUT -T $FILE -H $CONTENT_TYPE -H 'x-ms-version: 2020-02-10' -H "x-ms-date: $TIMESTAMP" "$STORAGE_URL"

    }
}

push_file()
```

Say for example I wanted to compress both `$FILE` and `$LOG_FILE`, or one and not the other. Or, any number of files for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would stop using global variables

```sh
compress_file() {
    local file
    for file in "$@"; do
        gzip "$file"
    done
}
```

and call the function like

```sh
compress_file "$FILE" "$LOG_FILE"
```

All the arguments to a function (aka positional parameters) live in the `"$@"` array-like variable